# What is the use of Universal trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traits

From the documentation, a universal trait can be used for value class:

A value class can only extend universal traits and cannot be extended itself. A universal trait is a trait that extends Any, only has defs as members, and does no initialization. Universal traits allow basic inheritance of methods for value classes, but they incur the overhead of allocation.

- How else universal trait can be used in Scala?

Comment: it can be used to make somethings of universal type. Ex you have some business models and make them as of universal type bizModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use in value classes is the only point of universal traits, and all of their limitations are chosen to allow this single use.